# How can I control this electronic door release with an Arduino?

Tags: lock

I am planning on fitting [this](http://www.icssecurity.co.uk/Electric_Locking_Devices_GK311-1224_ANSI_Release.asp) GK311-1224 ANSI Release to a door and using a simple switch and Arduino as triggers.

Are there any examples of a typical installation for a lock like this.

Answer (score 2):

That lock is simple: give it 12 or 24 volts and it opens. You will want to wire it through a relay as an Arduino won't be able to drive it directly.

Comment: They have information over on the Arduino website for using a driver transistor to operate a relay (from 5v, low current to higher coil current/voltage) and properly diode bypass the relay coil to cancel out inductive kick.